# In what order should I watch the Digimon movies and TV series?

Tags: suggested-order, anime, digimon

What is best order to watch the *Digimon* movies and TV series? I found [this list](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081106155239AAnwa3V), but it looks like it has some inaccuracies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

General points:

- Seasons 1 and 2 (Digimon Adventure and Digimon Adventure 02) are in the same continuity, and should be watched in order.
- Season 3 (Tamers) has Adventure and 02 exist as a TV show within the series, but it's not a major point.
- Seasons 6 and 7 (Xros Wars and Xros Wars 2) exist in the same continuity.
- Season 7 (Xros Wars 2: The Boy Hunters who Leapt Through Time) has some moments that work best if you've seen all the previous seasons (mostly near the end of the season).  Not required, though.
- All others are in an independent continuity from each other.

So it's perfectly reasonable to watch seasons in the order of 5, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2...  But not usually suggested.  Several of them have moments that are *intended* to be reminiscent of previous seasons, like the Thousand Points of Light in Season 5 (Savers/Data Squad) back to 02.

As for the movies, most of them are a side story of some sort with no impact on the main storyline.  But you should know who the characters are, which means watching the movies after the series.

Notes on the [Movies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon#Movies):

- *Digimon Adventure*, Part 1 of the US-released *Digimon: The Movie*.  While it takes place before Season 1, don't watch it until you've seen (most of) Adventure!  There's a bit of a mystery the children are trying to figure out during the course of the season, and this movie *is* the true events of that mystery.
- *Digimon Adventure: Our War Game*, Part 2 of the US-released *Digimon: The Movie*.  This takes place entirely after Season 1, before Season 2.  There's a short reference to the final scenes of the season finale.
- *Digimon Adventure 02: Digimon Hurricane Touchdown / Supreme Evolution! The Golden Digimentals*, Part 3 of the US-released *Digimon: The Movie*.  Takes place at some unspecified time during Season 2, if I recall correctly.  I don't think the events in the finale of 02 have happened by the time this movie takes place (and *definitely* not the events mentioned in the epilogue).
- *Diablomon Strikes Back*, I think takes place in a similarly unspecified time near the end of Season 2.
- *Digimon Tamers: Battle of Adventurers* takes place after episode 18 in the series, and *Digimon Tamers: Runaway Locomon* takes place after the final episode of the series.
- Given the ending of Season 4 (Frontier), that movie *definitely* takes place at some point during it.  Given the evolutions used, it would be nearer the end of the season.
- The 8th movie, *X-Evolution*, is a completely standalone CGI movie and only has Digimon characters.  Some species are familiar, but none of the characters are from the series.
- The Savers movie takes place entirely outside the continuity of the series, and is considered by Toei Animation to be non-canon.

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to work out some, Digimon movie 1 (Digimon Adventure) is before the first series its also the pilot episode. Digimon movie 2 (Our War Game)  is after the first series and before adventure 02, it kinda links them up as you have a young Yoli un it,. Digimon movie 3 (Digimon Hurricane Touchdown / Supreme Evolution! The Golden Digimentals) based on Veemon being able to golden armor digivolve but not normal digivolve and no Ken I could only place it in between episode 21 the crest of kindness and episode 22 Davis cries wolfmon. The Digimon movie is those three movies but with parts cut out and put together badly don't bother. Digimon movie 5 (Revenge of Diaboromon) is set after 02 episode 50 a million points of light. Digimon movie 6 (Battle of adventures) is definitely after Renamon gets to her ultimate level episode 18 digital beauty and 19 Impmons last stand  but definitely before episode 23. Then the second tamers movie happens a few months after the series has Finnished. Then Adventure Tri. There are also 3 mangas that link up Adventure, Adventure 02 and tamers. All the others aren't specified but crossed wars (hate this series except this one episode where the digidestend from season 1-6 appear). http://digimon.wikia.com/wiki/Fan:Digimon_Anime_Timeline here's a link for info.

Comment: As it is, this answer is difficult to understand.